# Get clicked Image properties

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap, imageview

Imagine a gallery application (sort of).
But instead of gallery I want to present a choice in form of 10 images displayed onto the screen.

How should you detect the one that user has clicked on?
What is a best way to implement this? Should I use ImageView and onClick method?
Imagine implementing onClick event for a 100 ImageViews?

?for every ImageView displayed onto the screen check if it contains user touch coordinates?

Same question bothers me for how to detect if the user has touched a Bitmap drawn onto a canvas.

Java, Android.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) with an ImageView in your list item's layout xml.

You can create a clickable [ViewHolder](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.ViewHolder) like this:

```
class ClickableViewHolder(final override val containerView: View, onClick: (position: Int) -> Unit) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(containerView) {

    init {
        containerView.setOnClickListener {
            val pos = absoluteAdapterPosition

            // check if item still exists
            if (pos != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                onClick(pos)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage in your [Adapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter) class:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false)
    return ClickableViewHolder(v) { position: Int ->
        getItem(position)?.let {
            //Do something here
        }
    }
}
```